# Billboard.js 3.5.1 with angular 6.0 gives ERROR TypeError: t.hasType is not a function when ng serve --prod

Tags: angular, billboard.js

I try to use Billboard.js with an angular6.0 application
when i run with ng serve  , application works fine.
when I run with ng serve --prod, application gives the following error when application gerenates chart (bb.generate)

main.19bd664034f5a0e96060.js:formatted:7402 ERROR TypeError: t.hasType is not a function
at main.19bd664034f5a0e96060.js:formatted:66053:39
at e.init (main.19bd664034f5a0e96060.js:formatted:66067:22)
at new e (main.19bd664034f5a0e96060.js:formatted:66471:23)
at Object.generate (main.19bd664034f5a0e96060.js:formatted:69686:29)
at e.ngAfterViewInit (main.19bd664034f5a0e96060.js:formatted:139959:35)
at fa (main.19bd664034f5a0e96060.js:formatted:11674:55)
at ha (main.19bd664034f5a0e96060.js:formatted:11662:36)
at da (main.19bd664034f5a0e96060.js:formatted:11655:60)
at Pa (main.19bd664034f5a0e96060.js:formatted:12147:17)

package.json dependencies

> "dependencies": {
> "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
> "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
> "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
> "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
> "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
> "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
> "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
> "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
> "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
> "billboard.js": "3.5.1",
> "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
> ....

angular.json

> ```
>         "scripts": [
> ```

```
          "node_modules/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.js",
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Can I Use this version of billboard with angular 6

Answer (score 0):

Looks like having issue importing & compiling pure ESM from Angular 6.
Try importing CJS dist file as below example.

Tested on latest Angular 14 also and worked without issue.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import bb from "billboard.js/dist/billboard.js";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    bb.generate({
      data: {
        columns: [
          ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
          ["data2", 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ],
        type: "bar"
      },
      bindto: "#chart"
    });
  }
}
```